# jQuery - select and group a set of elements by container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I need to select and group a set of image links based on their `<DIV>` or `<UL>` container.

For example, in this HTML: select the first two links, attach my function on them, select the next two links, run the function ... and so on

```
DIV
  LINK
  LINK

  DIV
    LINK
    LINK

    UL
      LINK
      LINK
    /UL

  /DIV

  UL
    LINK
    LINK
  /UL

/DIV

LINK
LINK

...
```

(each div/ul can have any number of links)

Right now I have this:

```
$('div').each(function(index){
  var elements = $(this).find('a').filter(function(){
    return !!this.href.match('(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png|\.gif)$');
  });

  console.log('------' + index + '------');
  console.log(elements);
});
```

which filters down the links to only to ones that are images.
but it doesn't really group them like I want and my function runs more than once on the same element...

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is your ultimate outcome? Couldn't you just do `$("a").filter(function(){}).DoSomething()`?

Comment: yes, but I need some kind of unique ID for each group of links, I though of using the `index` of the div/ul...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you probably have elements between the DIV's/UL's and the A, such as LI, you can start by selecting the A's and "group" them:

```
var groups =  [];
$('a')
  .filter(function(){ return !!this.href.match('(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png|\.gif)$'); })
  .map(function(idx,el) { return [$(this).closest("div, ul"), $(this)]; })
  .each(function(idx,el) { 
        var c= el[0];
        var imglink = el[1];
        if(!c.data("groupId")) {
           c.data("groupId", groups.length);
           groups.push({ "container": c, "links": [] });
        }
        groups[c.data("groupId")].links.push(imglink);
  });

// optional: remove the "groupId" data() from the container DOM elements:
$.each(groups, function(idx,el) { el.container.data("groupId", null); });
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to group things together maybe something like this will work for you.

```
$("div, ul, body").each(function(index, elm) {
    $(elm).children("a").text(function(i, text) {
        return text + "index: " + index;
    });
    $(elm).children("li").children("a").text(function(i, text) {
        return text + "index: " + index;
    });
});
```

With your markup:

```
<DIV>
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <DIV>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        <a href="#">Link 4</a>
        <UL>
            <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
        </UL>
    </DIV>
    <UL>
        <li><a href="#">Link 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 8</a></li>
    </UL>

</DIV>
<a href="#">Link 9</a>
<a href="#">Link 10</a>
```

Will produce the following:

```
Link 1index: 1 Link 2index: 1
Link 3index: 2 Link 4index: 2
Link 5index: 3
Link 6index: 3
Link 7index: 4
Link 8index: 4
Link 9index: 0 Link 10index: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want but I'm not sure exactly what you want to do to the elements:

```
   $('div > img').each(function(index) {

      if ((index % 4) === 1)
        // do something to every first element in a group of 4
      if ((index % 4) === 2)
        // do something to every second element in a group of 4
      if ((index % 4) === 3)
        // do something to every third element in a group of 4
      if ((index % 4) === 0)
        // do something to every fourth element in a group of 4
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you not use the selector with a child property?

ie:

```
$('div, ul').each(function(index){
    var elements = $(this).child('a');
    //run foreach on elements
});
```

The above will select all divs and uls (might want to apply a specific style or something here to only select the ones you want) then it gets the child a elements.